# Find the volume of the region bounded by the paraboloids $z = 2x^2 + y^2$ and $z = 12 - x^2 - 2y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the region bounded by the paraboloids $z = 2x^2 + y^2$ and $z = 12 - x^2 - 2y^2$

The answer says $24\pi$ but I just never got it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the polar coordinates, you can easily get the answer.

First you find the intersection of the two surfaces, which is $$x^2+y^2=4$$ or in polar coordinates it is r=2.

The integral for the volume is $$ V= \int _0^{2\pi} \int _0^2 (12-3r^2)rdr d\theta $$

Which results in $$V=24\pi$$